# ASP.NET MVC Override user in Windows authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm working in a small sap.net mvc intranet application and need to create the following behavior:

1. Use windows authentication using the current user
2. If the user has a specific trait (kiosk account), prevent login and display a login page
3. This new logon will be authenticated using AD and if valid, replace the initial user (Controller.Context.User.Identity.Name)

   [Authorize] tags need to work.

What would be the right approach for this?

EDIT: what I need to know is how I replace the implicit user with the one that logons manually

Comment: How do I know if user has `kiosk account` ?

Comment: are you really talking about federation using ADFS?

Comment: @Chetan Ranpariya it's based on the username, I got that covered

Comment: @ADyson in permises AD domain (I can take care of that with DirectoryServices)

Comment: Yes I realise that. I was referring to what you might need to add in order to achieve your goal

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use another user context try to use winapi function CreateProcessWithLogonW or CreateProcessWithTokenW